# Let’s all play 'Tag'?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Just wanted to have a quick say about tags,

If you read a question and it has a tag of [wine](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wine)  and the question is about [red-wine](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-wine)  please edit the question and re-tag as appropriate this is all in the hope to narrow down some of the question tags as we don't want tags to become too broad so if somebody has tagged a question with [rum](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rum)  and it is about [white-rum](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/white-rum)  then re-tag

just thought that i would put the message out there that this should be done it is not considered rude to re-tag a question it is simply making the site better and allowing people to finds the questions and answers that they need

Comment: OK, that all makes sense.  At last someone on SE makes sense to me!